# object sender listviewitem .text property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, object, sender

I am trying to access listviewitem selectitem text property via object sender.  how do I do this?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ListViewItem LS = new ListViewItem(@"c:\windows\explorer.exe");
   ListViewItem LS1 = new ListViewItem(@"c:\windows\notepad.exe");
   listView1.Items.Add(LS);
   listView1.Items.Add(LS1);
}


private void listView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // ???? how do I get listviewitem.text property here based on item selected 
   // ?? am i using the right eventhandler?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the SelectedItems property:

```
if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text // the text of the first selected item
```

Answer (score 0):

Access it simply by using the `ListView`itself

```
myListView.SelectedItems[0].Text
```